# Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to implement SQL query in Data Spring using this query:

```
public List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> findPaymentTransactionsDailyFacts(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date) {

        String hql = "SELECT DATE(date) AS Date, SUM(volume) AS amount, COUNT(*) AS number_of_transactions " + 
                " FROM " + PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts.class.getName() + " WHERE (date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date )" + 
                " GROUP BY DATE(date)";

        TypedQuery<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts.class).setParameter("start_date", start_date).setParameter("end_date", end_date);
        List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> data = query.getResultList();
        return data;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
01:23:16,208 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 01:23:16.206 [default task-1] ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/dashboard/volumes/USD] due to exception [Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [org.datalis.plugin.entity.PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts]]
01:23:16,208 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [org.datalis.plugin.entity.PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts]
01:23:16,208 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.resultClassChecking(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:783)
01:23:16,208 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:730)
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: JPQL has well documented SELECT clause `new RESULTCLASS(...)` syntax to allow for massaging multiple returns into a single object for a row. Perhaps you ought to read up on it

Comment: Can you give me hint idea how to edit the code?

Comment: I did. Just go to any decent JPA docs and read about the constructor syntax